# C++ unicode (or wstring?) equivalent for (char)

Tags: c++, unicode

Can somebody please tell me what would be the Unicode equivalent for "(char)"?

For ASCII I always used for example

```
 (char)(7)
```

Now I want to do the same but for Unicode.

But

```
 (wchar_t)(7)
```

did not work out, and wchar does not exist.

I want to pass this (possible) Unicode character to a function that accepts a wstring.

Or in other words:
How can I programmatically create a wstring from a unicode character value (like 7 for TAB)?

Comment: Could you show some code, please? These fragments aren't very useful

Comment: "Did not work out" is not enough of a problem description. I don't think anyone has any idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: C++ isn't ASCII-aware IIRC, but in C++11 `char` must be able to store an 8-bit UTF-8 code unit; there's also char16_t and char32_t (with at least 16 and 32 bit respectively). Note a single glyph can be represented by multiple UTF-8/-16 code units, therefore there's no exact equivalent to a `char` interpreted as an ASCII character.

Comment: I don't know what "ASCII-awareness" is, but it sounds completely useless to me. And in any case, C++ is aware of ASCII in footnote 14.

Comment: Maybe I've written it a bit hastily. The encoding of the characters is implementation-defined, it's not that C++ relies or explicitly uses ASCII (besides that footnote). You can use `char`s to store ASCII-encoded glyphs because of this footnote and the minimum size of `char` / byte. For Unicode or a specific Unicode encoding, it's different.

Comment: Tab is U+0009, not U+0007. `'\t'` and `L'\t'` probably work too.

Comment: C++ unicode equivalent for char is, .... char. 
http://utf8everywhere.org

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to pass this (possible) Unicode character to a function that accepts a `wstring`.

Then you'll need to make a `wstring`, just as you would have to make a `string` from a `char` if you needed to pass an ASCII character to a function accepting a `string`.

```
function(std::wstring(1, 7)); // length 1, filled with value 7
```

Answer (score 0):

In memory data is not stored in Unicode. Unicode provides a unique number for every (well, a whole lot) of characters used on computers.

In memory, characters are encoded: mapping byte values to Unicode numbers.

What encoding are you using?

- [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8): Each character is mapped to a 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, or 6 byte sequences.
- [UTF-16](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16): Each character is mapped to a 2 or 4 byte sequence.
- UCS-2: An incomplete mapping of most characters into a 2 byte sequence.
- [UTF-32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32): Each character is mapped to a 4 byte sequence.

wchar_t in win32 is 16-bit and characters are expected to be encoded in <strike>UCS-2</strike> [UTF-16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374081%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

wchar_t on most *NIXes is 32-bit and characters are expected to be encoded in UTF-32.

**UPDATE**

Huh, looks like I'm old. My last work was in VS2005 and there was still references to UCS-2 as the internal encoding, but I guess even that was already out of date.

Comment: Woah, are you a time traveller? If not, why are you talking about behaviour from the last millenium? Windows has been using UTF-16 for "a while" now.

Comment: Functions e.g. of the Windows SDK might expect `wchar_t`-strings to be encoded, but I think they'd rather expect them to be encoded in UTF-16.

Comment: UTF-16 is used for text in the OS API in Microsoft Windows 2000/XP/2003/Vista/CE. Older Windows NT systems (prior to Windows 2000) only support UCS-2.